# Проблема с векторными изображениями на Android 4

Tags: android, vector

Здравствуйте. Несколько дней не могу разобраться почему при использовании векторных иконок xml на андроид 4 вылетает эксепшн.

Вот сама разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context="app.second.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/square_blue_btn"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_btn" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/square_blue_btn"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_btn" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/square_blue_btn"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

В качестве фону у этих картинок указаны векторные иконки в xml drawable виде. В частности вот иконка square_btn имеет такую разметку

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:height="150dp"
    android:viewportWidth="150"
    android:viewportHeight="150">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#0761CB"
        android:pathData="M138.9,75.8 C139.7,100.7,139.5,130.7,109.2,136.4
C85.5,140.8,44.3,143.1,24.2,127.5 C4.5,112.2,10.8,71.4,14.6,50.2
C19.9,21,41.9,12.9,68.1,11.4 C85.3,10.4,108.9,9.3,123.1,21.5
C137.5,34,137.8,58.3,138.9,75.8 C139.3,82.8,147.7,83.4,147.2,75.9
C145.9,52.5,147.2,14.2,118.7,6 C93.1,-1.2,55.1,-0.5,29.9,8.6
C3,18.4,4,57.1,3.1,80.1 C2.1,104.9,0.7,136.9,31.4,143
C59.6,148.7,97.7,150.8,125.8,143.3 C153.3,135.9,148.1,97.3,147.2,76
C146.9,68.5,138.7,68.8,138.9,75.8 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#3BA4FF"
        android:pathData="M143.1,75.9 C143.9,92.7,146.9,118.5,133.4,131.9 C119.7,145.4,93,142.8,75.8,142.5
C58.3,142.2,31.7,143.6,17.8,130.1 C4.3,116.9,6.7,92.5,7.5,75.8
C8.4,58.3,8.6,34.2,22.1,20.6 C35.4,7.2,58.6,7.2,75.7,6.9
C92.5,6.6,115.9,5.5,128.9,18.9 C142.5,32.8,142.2,58.2,143.1,75.9 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#3BD5FF"
        android:pathData="M75.7,6.9 C58.6,7.2,35.4,7.2,22.1,20.6 C8.6,34.2,8.4,58.3,7.5,75.8
C7.1,84,7,92.3,7.5,100.6 C9.1,82.7,11,64.3,17,47.3 C23.1,29.8,37.1,20,54.8,16.7
C74.5,13.1,95.6,11.5,115.6,13.7 C118.7,14,121.7,14.6,124.5,15.2
C110.5,6,91.5,6.6,75.7,6.9 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#088BF4"
        android:pathData="M75.7,142.5 C92.9,142.8,119.6,145.4,133.3,131.9 C146.8,118.5,143.7,92.8,143,75.9
C142.8,70.8,142.7,65.6,142.3,60.8 C141.6,64,140.5,67.4,139.7,70.4
C133.4,93,122.3,111,97.7,115.2 C75.7,119,49.2,120.5,27.8,112.4
C22.8,110.5,18.3,107.8,15.4,103.2 C12.4,98.6,11.1,92.1,9.9,85.3
C9.1,80.8,8.4,76,7.8,71.1 C7.7,72.7,7.6,74.2,7.5,75.8
C6.8,92.6,4.3,116.9,17.8,130 C31.7,143.6,58.2,142.1,75.7,142.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#2198FF"
        android:pathData="M75.7,142.5 C96.7,142.9,133.1,146.5,140.3,119.6
C136.1,124.9,130.6,128.5,123.6,130.7 C101,137.9,74.2,136.5,50.9,136.3
C41.2,136.2,31.9,135.5,22.2,133.5 C37.8,142.7,58.6,142.1,75.7,142.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#3BA4FF"
        android:pathData="M126.5,119.5 C127,121.4,125.8,122.5,123.9,122 C122,121.6,120.1,119.8,119.7,118
C119.3,116.2,120.5,115,122.3,115.4 C124.2,115.8,126,117.7,126.5,119.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M49.9,25.5 C52.2,28.4,48.3,33.6,41.9,37.1 C35.4,40.6,28.8,41,26.5,37.7
S27.2,29.1,33.6,25.9 S47.7,22.6,49.9,25.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M62,22.5 C62.1,24.5,60.3,26.1,57.9,25.9 C55.5,25.7,53.4,23.9,53.2,21.8
C53,19.8,54.8,18.3,57.2,18.5 C59.7,18.7,61.9,20.5,62,22.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#0ACCFF"
        android:pathData="M46.8,42.6 C35.2,42.6,25.8,50.3,25.8,59.9 C25.8,69.4,35.2,77.2,46.8,77.2
S67.8,69.5,67.8,59.9 C67.8,50.3,58.4,42.6,46.8,42.6 Z M44.5,68.3
C37.9,68.3,32.5,64.3,32.5,59.5 C32.5,54.6,37.9,50.7,44.5,50.7
C51.1,50.7,56.5,54.7,56.5,59.5 C56.5,64.3,51.1,68.3,44.5,68.3 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#0ACCFF"
        android:pathData="M102.1,42.6 C95.8,42.6,90.8,48.3,90.8,55.2 S95.9,67.8,102.1,67.8
C108.4,67.8,113.4,62.1,113.4,55.2 S108.4,42.6,102.1,42.6 Z M100.9,61.4
C97.3,61.4,94.4,58.5,94.4,54.9 C94.4,51.3,97.3,48.4,100.9,48.4
C104.5,48.4,107.4,51.3,107.4,54.9 C107.3,58.5,104.4,61.4,100.9,61.4 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#0ACCFF"
        android:pathData="M88.6,91.4 C82,85,73.1,83.6,68.7,88.2 C64.3,92.8,66.1,101.6,72.6,107.9
C79.2,114.2,88.1,115.6,92.5,111.1 C97,106.5,95.2,97.7,88.6,91.4 Z M75.5,102.4
C71.8,98.8,70.5,94,72.8,91.6 C75.1,89.3,79.9,90.3,83.7,93.9
C87.4,97.5,88.7,102.3,86.4,104.7 C84.1,107,79.2,106,75.5,102.4 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#0ACCFF"
        android:pathData="M49.1,87.5 C44.5,83,37.6,82.6,33.7,86.6 C29.9,90.6,30.5,97.5,35.2,101.9
C39.8,106.4,46.7,106.8,50.6,102.8 C54.4,98.8,53.7,92,49.1,87.5 Z M37.8,97.4
C35.2,94.9,34.6,91.1,36.6,89.1 C38.6,87.1,42.3,87.5,45,90
C47.6,92.5,48.2,96.3,46.2,98.3 C44.2,100.3,40.5,99.9,37.8,97.4 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#0ACCFF"
        android:pathData="M93.3,17.3 C87.4,19.8,84.3,26,86.5,31.1 C88.7,36.2,95.3,38.3,101.2,35.7
C107.1,33.2,110.2,27,108,21.9 C105.8,16.9,99.2,14.8,93.3,17.3 Z M98,31.6
C94.6,33,91,32.1,89.9,29.5 S90.6,23.6,94,22.1 C97.4,20.7,101,21.6,102.1,24.2
S101.4,30.1,98,31.6 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#0ACCFF"
        android:pathData="M113.4,71.9 C106.5,74.9,103.1,82.4,105.8,88.7 C108.5,95,116.3,97.8,123.2,94.8
C130.1,91.8,133.5,84.3,130.8,78 C128,71.6,120.3,68.9,113.4,71.9 Z M119.3,89.5
C115.4,91.2,111.1,89.9,109.7,86.7 C108.3,83.5,110.4,79.5,114.3,77.8
C118.2,76.1,122.5,77.4,123.9,80.6 C125.3,83.8,123.2,87.8,119.3,89.5 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#0ACCFF"
        android:pathData="M83,61.1 C86.2585,61.1,88.9,63.8311,88.9,67.2 C88.9,70.5689,86.2585,73.3,83,73.3
C79.7415,73.3,77.1,70.5689,77.1,67.2 C77.1,63.8311,79.7415,61.1,83,61.1 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#0ACCFF"
        android:pathData="M18.4,70.4 C21.3271,70.4,23.7,73.1311,23.7,76.5
C23.7,79.8689,21.3271,82.6,18.4,82.6 C15.4729,82.6,13.1,79.8689,13.1,76.5
C13.1,73.1311,15.4729,70.4,18.4,70.4 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#0ACCFF"
        android:pathData="M129.7,33.7 C132.958,33.7,135.6,36.1624,135.6,39.2
C135.6,42.2376,132.958,44.7,129.7,44.7 C126.442,44.7,123.8,42.2376,123.8,39.2
C123.8,36.1624,126.442,33.7,129.7,33.7 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#2198FF"
        android:pathData="M38.5,116.4 C40.8748,116.4,42.8,118.325,42.8,120.7
C42.8,123.075,40.8748,125,38.5,125 C36.1252,125,34.2,123.075,34.2,120.7
C34.2,118.325,36.1252,116.4,38.5,116.4 Z" />
</vector>
```

И вот мне выбрасывает такое исключение

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.second/app.second.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class ImageButton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class ImageButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at app.second.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/square_blue_btn.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020099
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1958)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:60)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:56)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at app.second.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1955)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330) 
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114) 
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:60) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:56) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087) 
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at app.second.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

В Gradle содержится следующая информация

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.second"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как можно в качестве фонового изображения указывать векторные изображения в андроид ниже чем 5

Comment: Вот это должно помочь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915974/23-2-0-set-vector-drawable-as-background-in-4-x

Comment: Не очень понял где это прописать? Resources resources = context.getResources(Resources, int, Theme);
Theme theme = context.getTheme();
Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, R.drawable.drawable, theme);

Comment: Программно для каждой вьюшки. Получаете таким образом `Drawable` и задаете вашей `ImageView` его в качестве бэкграунда.

Comment: Хм, попробую сейчас.

Comment: что-то у меня тут ругается после импортов классов. Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources(Resources, int,Resources.Theme);

Comment: А есть полегче способ, чтобы для каждой вьюшки не прописывать?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нет. А что сложного? Создали метод, в который передаете нужную вью и id ресурса, а там 4 строчки...

Comment: Можете привести пример? Я те три строчки скопировал к себе и импортировал классы на первую строчку ругается компилятор

Comment: Написал в ответ. Там была ошибка с `getResources()`. Но уж лучше было самостоятельно подумать и погуглить. Не будут же всегда за Вас писать код.

Answer (score 1):

Пример установки векторного ресурса в `background`:

```
setBackground(imageView, R.drawable.your_drawable);

private void setBackground(View target, @DrawableRes int resId) {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        Resources.Theme theme = getTheme();
        Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, resId, theme);
        target.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

Методы `getTheme()` и `getResources()` вызываются из контекста.
Метод `setBackground()` вызывайте там, где заполняете вью.

Comment: Ругается на метод target.setBackground(drawable); Пишет Call requires API level 16 (current min is 15): android.view.View#setBackground

Comment: А для апи 15 есть какой-то способ?

Comment: Тогда `setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)`. Он deprecated, но с Вашей версией иначе никак.

Comment: ну пропишу условие. для 15 setBackgroundDrawable, для версий выше setBackground

Comment: Все равно такие же эксепшены выбрасывает